# Class which handles tasks in thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I want to make a class which as long as an instance of it is alive, keeps a thread (worker) going and when someone calls a method on it - `performTaskWithData:(NSData*)data` - then it should process this data in its worker thread.
If additional data is sent while an operation is taking place, then this new data/operation should be queued until the previous processing is done.

I need each instance of this helper class to hold one single worker thread (i.e. the same thread should handle all the processing).

How should I go about doing this?
NSRunLoop? Synchronize access to data block being passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in iOS4, [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) provides by far the simplest and most powerful interface to multithreaded programming.

If you're a registered developer, go watch some of the WWDC videos from 2010 about it. It's intimidating at first, but it's actually really simple and good.

Comment: Same question as above - is this guaranteed to use the same thread for every operation in the queue?

Comment: You don't have to think about that. You have queued processes, and you can talk about those processes. Go research it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly with NSThreads and run loops.  However, I would consider using [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)s, one per instance of your class and set the maximum concurrency of the queue to 1.  Your `performTaskWithData:` would simply add a new instance of a subclass of `NSOperation` to the queue and that's it.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to use the same thread for every operation?

Comment: No, it guarantees that the tasks are definitely performed sequentially, but not necessarily on the identical thread. The exact thread no longer matters.